# wlan0 disappears after running airmon-ng on Android running Kali Linux

Tags: linux, android, wlan, airmon-ng

LG G3 Android 5.0 device, rooted with Linux Deploy app, Kali Linux 2.0 installed with all components.

I'm connected to Kali Linux through SSH and trying to monitor wireless traffic.

```
$ ifconfig wlan0
wlan0     Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 34:...:b9  
          inet addr:172.20.10.6  Bcast:172.20.10.15  Mask:255.255.255.240
          inet6 addr: f0...b9/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:428 errors:0 dropped:1 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:477 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:185189 (180.8 KiB)  TX bytes:91160 (89.0 KiB)


$ airmon-ng 

PHY Interface   Driver      Chipset

phy0    p2p0        wcnss_wlan  Not pci, usb, or sdio
phy0    wlan0       wcnss_wlan  Not pci, usb, or sdio


$ airmon-ng start wlan0

Found 2 processes that could cause trouble.
If airodump-ng, aireplay-ng or airtun-ng stops working after
a short period of time, you may want to kill (some of) them!

  PID Name
1588 wpa_supplicant
8679 dhcpcd

PHY     Interface       Driver          Chipset

phy0    p2p0            wcnss_wlan      Not pci, usb, or sdio
phy0    wlan0           wcnss_wlan      Not pci, usb, or sdio
Failed to set wlan0mon up using ip
command failed: No such device (-19)

                (mac80211 monitor mode vif enabled for [phy0]wlan0 on [phy0]wlan0mon)
                (mac80211 station mode vif disabled for [phy0]wlan0)
```

After this `wlan0` is no longer available and it does not appear in `ifconfig`. There doesn't seem to be any running aircrack-ng process, the only way I managed to bring it back is by restarting the phone.

```
# after running airmon-ng start wlan0
$ airmon-ng 

PHY Interface   Driver      Chipset

phy0    p2p0        wcnss_wlan  Not pci, usb, or sdio
```

What is the cause for this failure?

Comment: Have you read the part of the Aircrack documentation that tells you how to reset the interface? http://www.aircrack-ng.org/doku.php?id=airmon-ng

Comment: if you're referring to `network-manager`, then there's no such service.

Comment: I wouldn't expect there to be a `network-manager` on a phone. I suppose there might be one in Kali, though. However, no, I wasn't referring to that. There are several parts in that documentation that discuss starting _and stopping_ the monitor interfaces.

Comment: it fails with `No such device` error, probably because `wlan0` isn't visible anymore.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This may happen if `wlan0` WiFi adapter does not support monitor mode.

Specifically, LG G3's internal WiFi device does not support monitor mode.